# React Native Debugger app will not open - debugger-ui opens in Chrome instead

Tags: debugging, react-native, expo

My project is a create react native app project, using expo. I installed the react-native-debugger app a while back to debug redux and it was working fine. Recently, for an unknown reason, when debugging JS remotely it will only open http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui/ in Chrome, and will not connect to the React Native Debugger App. I have no idea why this has suddenly broken. This doesn't work for me as I can't use redux dev tools this way

My package.json has the following:

```
"devDependencies": {
"jest-expo": "30.0.0",
"react-native-debugger-open": "^0.3.17"
}
```

OS: Mac OS Mojave

Any ideas on how I can get expo to start using the desktop app again? I don't know what else to do beyond setting up the package.json correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Can't comment cause my rep is under 50,
but I face the same issue on `ubuntu 16.04` since this week.

Edit:

You can still use [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron) in the meantime.

[Here](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/blob/master/docs/quick-start-react-native.md) is the quick start section for `react-native`